# Finding Win CMD columns (gives result+error)

Tags: php, windows, cmd, exec, command-line-interface

I have problem with following script:

`$ exec('mode con /status', $tmp); print_r($tmp);`

It runs the command and gives me result, but also I get every time error message too:

`The system cannot find the path specified.`

I just want get terminal window size `$COLS` x `$ROWS`

Used system: PHP 5.4 + Win7

Test results here:
`C:\@home\Devel>C:\php\php.exe -v
PHP 5.4.13 (cli) (built: Mar 15 2013 02:05:59)
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.2.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2013, by Derick Rethans`

C:\@home\Devel>C:\php\php.exe -r "exec('mode con /status', $tmp); print_r($tmp);"
**The system cannot find the path specified.**
Array
(
    [0] =>
    [1] => Status for device CON:
    [2] => ----------------------
    [3] =>     Lines:          1200
    [4] =>     Columns:        160
    [5] =>     Keyboard rate:  31
    [6] =>     Keyboard delay: 0
    [7] =>     Code page:      775
    [8] =>
)

How can I get rid of this error message!?!

Thanks.

Comment: I tried exactly what you have done, and it does work without errors.